# google's protobuf from golang to c# - Protocol message contained an invalid tag (zero)

Tags: c#, go, protocol-buffers

I don't have problem when i send a byte packet from c# to Golang using protobuf. But when i send a byte from Golang to c# get error.

I use this code in c# to get protobuf sent by golang:

```
 Stream stream = new MemoryStream(m);
        PRSData data;
        data = PRSData.Parser.ParseFrom(stream);
        print(data);
```

Then i get this error in c#:

> InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message contained an invalid
>   tag (zero). Google.Protobuf.CodedInputStream.ReadTag ()

Also the structure of protobuf that c# generates is right but the golang's one is incorrect

The protobuf structure generated by c# is:

```
{ "action": "move", "id": "player_361", "room": "SyONuNo0W", "pos": { "x": 74.423, "y": -0.04, "z": 10.903 } }
```

The protobuf structure generated by golang is:

```
action:"move" id:"player_361" room:"SyONuNo0W" pos:<x:74.423 y:-0.04 z:10.903 >
```

Please help me working with protobuf in c# and Golang and truly conversions between them.

Comment: Are you using the binary layout? Or the json layout? It sounds like the binary, but the examples at the bottom are json. Is the data accidentally padded? If it is binary, does it work OK at https://protogen.marcgravell.com/decode ? (you can use that page to verify binary from files, hex, or base-64) - note my hunch here is padding after the payload

Comment: I send data like this from c#  
`PRSData data = ... portobyf ;
byte[] buf = ((Imessage)data).ToByteArray();`

Comment: great; now, if you take the hex, base-64 or file version of that and run it through /decode, it will tell you if the data is malformed. Knowledge of whether it is malformed or not is the first thing to get. However, in your golang code it isn't obvious how you get `m`, and in the c# code it isn't obvious what you do with `buf`, so it is also entirely possible that you're accidentally padding during transfer. Heck, a really simple test you can do: compare the length of `buf` with the length of `m`. If they aren't the same: fix it. Then check the **contents**.

Comment: Ultimately, until you have checked that you received the right data (i.e. do `m` and `buf` contain exactly the same bytes), all bets are off.

Comment: Yes, you're right. the length of byte in c# is 1024 but in golang is 56.

In the code below the variable **size** is 56 bytes but in this line **m = (byte[])ar.AsyncState;** becomes 1024 bytes

'
int size = sckCommunication.EndReceiveFrom(ar, ref epRemote);

            if (size > 0)
            {   
               
                // used to help us on getting the data
                byte[] m = new byte[numberBytes];

                // gets the data
                m = (byte[])ar.AsyncState;
      }
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When reading from a socket into a buffer, you need to ensure that you correctly track *how much data you have*. In your example (comments), this is `size`, you you must make sure that any processing is restricted to that many bytes. Since you are using `MemoryStream`, you will note that there is a constructor that accepts the buffer and an offset (zero) and count (`size`).

Note that if you are dealing with multiple messages on a single socket, you will also need to handle "framing" - TCP does not guarantee to receive data in the same chunks in which it was sent - just the same bytes in the same order.

Comment: Thanks
The problem solved
I modified the line
byte[] m = new byte[numberBytes];
to
byte[] m = new byte[size];